# Java Nested Loop Triangle [Basic]

Tags: java, loops, nested, logic

So the task is to make the system output a triangle with spaces that increment in between x's like this(dashes added in place of space for readability):

xx
x-x
x--x
x---x
x----x
x-----x
x------x
x-------x

So, I've done this before and it seems easy enough, but the issue I'm having is getting the initial amount of spaces correct. I would like an example of how to do this and why it works as plainly stated as possible, thank you. Here's the code I have so far, along with the output:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("How many columns");
    col = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("#");
        for(int j = 0; j < (i+ 1); j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("#");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Output(when cols = 4):
x-x
x--x
x---x
x----x

All help is truly appreciated :)

Comment: Take it step-by-step, see what happens in step A before proceeding to step B...

Comment: The code that you've posted doesn't seem to compile. Did you mean `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);`?

Comment: try writing the logic out on paper first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[]args){
System.out.println("How many columns?");
int columns = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

for(int i=0; i<=columns; i++){
  String toPrint = "x";
  for(int cols=0; cols<i; cols++){
      toPrint+=" ";
  }
  System.out.println(toPrint+"x");

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think The problem is with the r value set initially. There is no need of new variable r to be set.

If i is less than j,  the loop doesn't get executed first time, and the loop executes 1 step more than each previous iteration of outer for loop

Answer (score 0):

change condition for j like below. also you have declared variable as col and used it like cols. so make corrections first.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner; 
System.out.println("How many columns");
col = in.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
{
    System.out.print("#");
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("#");
    System.out.println();
}
```